# postgis ST_ConcaveHull from MULTIPOLYGON fails

Tags: postgis

I use PostGIS 2.1.1 to create some concave hulls from several polygons but sometimes it works and sometimes it fails depending on the shape of the polygons.

The following request

```
SELECT st_astext(ST_ConcaveHull(st_union(
ST_GeomFromText ('POLYGON(...)',
ST_GeomFromText ('POLYGON(...)')
),0.85)) As cc_hull
```

returns sometimes `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY` with the message

> NOTICE:  Too few points in geometry component at or near point 0 0

I tried to use `st_collect` instead of `st_union` with  the same result.
Also i tried `ST_MakeValid` etc..

here is an example that fails

```
> SELECT st_astext(ST_ConcaveHull(st_union(
ST_GeomFromText ('POLYGON((-0.7528611 46.2531213,-0.711708 46.240873,-0.68886 46.23969,-0.6850865 46.288144,-0.67921 46.29997,-0.673535 46.315953,-0.71736 46.30777,-0.741967 46.283543,-0.7528611 46.2531213))'),
ST_GeomFromText ('POLYGON((-0.8617425 46.3176727,-0.8471857 46.3337108,-0.8469636 46.3339572,-0.84576 46.335272,-0.8393793 46.3405319,-0.8355 46.341544,-0.804777 46.341832,-0.7754804 46.3182422,-0.76213 46.30547,-0.758752 46.300819,-0.753278 46.292984,-0.785317 46.281833,-0.8064719 46.2739175,-0.833606 46.270022,-0.846593 46.291528,-0.85837 46.310202,-0.8617425 46.3176727))')
),0.85)) As cc_hull
```

How to obtain a valid answer whatever the polygons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me:

`POLYGON((-0.803550808455445 46.3415902129884,-0.775116206238198 46.3186944988309,......,-0.803550808455445 46.3415902129884))
(1 row)`

Maybe your old version of postgis (mine is 2.4.3) still have bugs in this function ?

You can try to update postgres/postgis, or maybe (with crossing fingers) to copy/past the function (I tried with https://appgeodb.nancy.inra.fr/donnees/documentations/bdd/db_robot/structure/Functions/st_concavehull_public.html (random search for me) and rename it to be sure (like CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.st_concavehull2 ...) and I'm pretty sure it should work, otherwise I don't see where the problem is from (are you sure it's not somewhere else in your code?).

Comment: Work for me too with PostGIS 2.3.

Comment: Thank you. This looks like a bug on version 2.1.1.
I am going to upgrade PostGIS..
As advised, I tried to update the functions st_concavehull and _st_concavehull and ... it works (on simple examples for now). It seems to be a workaround.